# Fuzzy logical and integer programming

Tags: soft-question, fuzzy-logic

Is there any way of formulating linear/non-linear programming problems in terms of YES, NO, and MAYBE instead of just $0-1$ programming?

Comment: Either there is such way, or there is no such way, or there might be such way. In short, the answer is one of YES, NO, MAYBE. :-)

Comment: I believe the person who asked this question, didn't try to research this question.

Answer (score 4):

A google search for "fuzzy linear programming" yields [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=linear%20progamming%20fuzzy&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=QRb&pwst=1&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sa=X&ei=OBK3T630DpCg8QTgnN2sCg&ved=0CBYQvwUoAQ&q=fuzzy%20linear%20programming&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5207c285b2062f50&biw=1787&bih=829), and for "fuzzy nonlinear programming" yields [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=linear%20progamming%20fuzzy&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=sSb&pwst=1&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=fuzzy%20nonlinear%20programming&oq=fuzzy%20nonlinear%20programming&aq=f&aqi=g-c1g3&aql=1&gs_l=serp.3..0i7j0l3.59821.59832.0.59861.4.2.0.0.0.0.99.99.1.1.0.cqn,fixedpos=false,boost_normal=40,boost_high=40,cconf=0-95,min_length=2,rate_low=0-015,rate_high=0-015.1.0.0.tkVV3A07aQM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5207c285b2062f50&biw=1787&bih=829) (I recall I've seen such programming mentioned in fuzzy logic books before also... I think Klir and Yuan's "Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic: Theory and Applications" has a very,very short section on this).  So, unless I've misinterpreted something here, the answer is "yes".